# Hive performance GROUP BY versus MAX

Tags: hive

I have a table with columns `partner_id`, `dummy` and `clicks`. Now I want to perform the easy task to sum clicks by partner_id and dummy. But I have the extra knowledge that `dummy` is always constant for a a fixed partner_id. For example let's take the following table `data`:

```
partner_id  dummy  clicks
1           a      10
1           a      15
2           b      100
```

Now I want to do my aggregation to obtain this:

```
partner_id  dummy  clicks
1           a      25
2           b      100
```

The obvious solution is

```
SELECT
  partner_id,
  dummy,
  SUM(clicks)
FROM
  data
GROUP BY
  partner_id,
  dummy
```

But since I know that dummy is the same for every partner_id I can as well go for

```
SELECT
  partner_id,
  MAX(dummy) AS dummy,
  SUM(clicks)
FROM
  data
GROUP BY
  partner_id
```

**My question is if one option has a definite better performance** 
I do think that the second option has a better performance than the first, but I did find no resource to verify this. Looking at the stage plans for both queries they are very similar except for the obvious difference in the grouping phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 1 will definitely have a better performance. Depending on the size of your data, option 2 will require some additional processing during the aggregation to find the max (it will iterate the whole group to get the max), which you already know will be always the same  considering that the column "dummy" has the same value at group level. Considering the mapreduce framework behavior, option 1 and 2 will have the same effort and distribution during the group by, it does not matter if you add the column dummy or not to the group by.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  So what I want now is to understand why "it does not matter if you add the column dummy or not to the group by". I will do my research, feel free to point me at a resource though.

Comment: it is how hive distribute the data for the reduce phase in the mapred job. I recommend understand in detail how that part works